# Extract PDF form fields and their text descriptions from a PDF form

Tags: java, python, node.js, pdf

I'm looking to extract form fields as well as their text description from a PDF document.

Currently i'm able to extract the ids and names of fields using the XFDF signature. 
I can also extract the complete text of the PDF form.

What I need, however, is some kind of mapping between the field's description and the field itself (e.g. "fieldId": "field_description").

In the example below the red marked text "Family Name" would be the description and the blue marked field the corresponding field.

[Example of what I mean by description and field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqyiS.png).

Is this even possible with current tools like pdftk?
Are there any command line tools that can achieve this mapping or how could I achieve this in another way?

Comment: [Textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python_package.html) would be what I recommend, but [PyPDF2](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/) had some documentation mentioning a ```/Content``` object. It may be worth looking into.